# XMLHttpRequest different in IE8 vs. FireFox/Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-ajax, cross-browser, xmlhttprequest

I'm having a problem similar to [jQuery $.ajax Not Working in IE8 but it works on FireFox & Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721970/jquery-ajax-not-working-in-ie8-but-it-works-on-firefox-chrome), but with a different use case.

I'm using the jQuery Form plug-in to handle a file upload to an ASP.NET MVC controller, which sends the file off for parsing and processing. If an Exception is thrown, it should alert the user to the issue.

```
//client side code
//make an ajax call, sending the contents of the file
                    $("#ajaxUploadForm").ajaxSubmit({
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: '/plan/Something/ExcelImport',
                        iframe: true,
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").find("#my_progress").fadeIn();
                        },
                        success: function (data, textStatus) {
                            output = "<center><span class='flash'>" + data.message + "</span></center>";
                            $("#flash_message").html(output).fadeIn('slow');
                            setTimeout(function () { $("#flash_message").fadeOut() }, 5000);
                            cleanup();
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("XMLHttpRequest is " + XMLHttpRequest);
                            var contents = "";
                            for (prop in XMLHttpRequest) {
                                contents += "\na property is " + prop + " it's value is " + XMLHttpRequest[prop];
                            }
                            alert("the contents are " + contents);
                            alert("textStatus is " + textStatus);
                            alert("errorThrown is " + errorThrown);
                            //comes back in an HTML envelope. This should be parsed with regex, but I can't get it to work. Dirty hack
                            response = XMLHttpRequest.responseText.substring(XMLHttpRequest.responseText.indexOf("<body>"));
                            response = response.replace("<body>", "");
                            response = response.replace("</body>", "");
                            alert("There was a problem with the upload.\r\n" + response);
                        },
                        complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
                            $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").find("#my_progress").remove();
                            something_import.dialog('close');
                            something_import.dialog('destroy');
                        }
                    });

//server side code
public FileUploadJsonResult ExcelImport()
    {
        FileUploadJsonResult result = new FileUploadJsonResult();
        HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[0] as HttpPostedFileBase;
        if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)
            return new FileUploadJsonResult { Data = new { message = "File contained no data" } };
        String fileName = Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
        String timeStampedFile = fileName.Insert(fileName.IndexOf('.'),"_"+DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc());
        string savedFileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "tempo", timeStampedFile);
        hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName);
        try
        {
            result = ProcessFile(savedFileName, Request["Id"]) as FileUploadJsonResult;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e)
        {
            this.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            this.Response.StatusDescription = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest.ToString();
            Response.Write(e.Message);
            result = Json(new { message = e.Message, stackTrace = e.StackTrace }) as FileUploadJsonResult;  
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox. In IE, the XMLHttpRequest object coming back is different:

FF:[image]

IE:
[image]

I've been Googling around for differences between the browser implementations of XMLHttpRequest, but haven't found anything that deals specifically with this case. Stymied.

Comment: Inspect the request and response in fiddler for Chrome, Firefox & IE to see how they differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because of the `iframe` fallback strategy that `ajaxSubmit` employs. I think since the response gets posted into the `iframe` IE tries to figure out how to dipslay it and decides that it wants to ask you to download the response instead of just putting it in the `iframe`.

I came across this same situation a while ago and found an article (that I can't find now) that offered a workaround.

If you **surround your json response in a `textarea`** nobody is going to complain(IE,FF,Chrome,probably Safari) and you'll get your response parsed correctly.

E.g. if you are returning

```
{Id: 1, Name: 'Me'}
```

just return:

```
<textarea>{Id: 1, Name: 'Me'}</textarea>
```

You see now IE thinks it's html so it inserts it into the hidden `iframe`. Your `ajaxSubmit` function still gets called and parses the json correctly and then everybody's happy. :)

If you're using ASP.NET MVC you could shamelessly copy this extension method :)

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static ActionResult JsonSafe(this IController controller, object obj)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return new WriteResult(string.Format("<textarea>{0}</textarea>", serializer.Serialize(obj)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia article on [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) seems to give a good overview of the history behind the XMLHttpRequest.  It seems Microsoft and Mozilla developed/adopted their own versions of the object and hence why you are probably seeing different properties.

Here is a link to Microsoft's implementation of the [XMLHttpRequest interface members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874%28VS.85%29.aspx), which seem to match the properties in your alert.

Here is the a link to Mozilla's implementation of [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest).

So while we wait for the W3C to [standardize](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) the XMLHttpRequest you will continue to have different implementations across the browsers like you are seeing in this case.

For some added fun here is [Apple's](http://developer.apple.com/internet/webcontent/xmlhttpreq.html) and [Opera's](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/opera9/xhr/) specifications on XMLHttpRequest.