# JQuery AJAX issue in IE

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I'm having issue in AJAX call its working fine in Firefox and chrome but not in IE and keep hitting error function:

```
           $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: requestUrl,
                data: {
                    presentation_id: id_here,
                    application_ids: selectedAppIDs.join(',')
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (er) {

                },
                complete: function () {

                }
            });
```

am i missing something?

Comment: What type of error are you receiving?

Comment: Error Code is 500, but when I manually enter the URL in browser I can see the json response.

Comment: just out of curiousity.. what if you change it to a "get" instead of "post".

Comment: 500 is a server error-- so I wonder if IE is serializing the input differently than the other browsers. Is there a way to debug and see what the data looks like when it makes it to the server?

Comment: in your PHP Code: have you add a content-type? JSON?

Comment: @poldixd I'm doing this in asp.net and yes I've also tried to set the contentType but same issue.

Comment: If you manually enter the URL in the browser it will be a **GET**, not a **POST**. Are the endpoints for the GET/POST request the same? Also, that is the _exact_ JSON being returned? IE _correctly_ errors with JSON that has a [trailing comma](http://trailingcomma.com/) whereas other browsers _incorrectly_ allow it.

Comment: @ek_ny get request seems to be working fine but why not for post?

Comment: @andyb There are no trailing commas I've verified.

Comment: @Ali if you're using asp.net- then set a breakpoint in the controller and see how the data is getting passed. See what the difference is when you use IE and when you use the browsers which are working.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your page having any `un-closed div` or that kind of any syntax issues also.If it's there then fix those issues first.

Try below one.I have added `contentType.`

```
       $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: requestUrl,
                data: {
                    presentation_id: id_here,
                    application_ids: selectedAppIDs.join(',')
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (er) {

                },
                complete: function () {

                }
            });
```

For more information check [**jQuery.ajax()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and

[**jQuery $.ajax Not Working in IE8 but it works on FireFox & Chrome**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721970/jquery-ajax-not-working-in-ie8-but-it-works-on-firefox-chrome)

Comment: @Ali did you check mentioned url ?