# How can I get Ajax work on IE9 and IE8

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I am trying to use Ajax on IE9 and IE8 but could not make it.
I researched on Stackoverflow and on the other pages and tried all the ways on there.
This is the code which I currently have.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://example.com' + new Date().getTime(),
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Authorization Key");
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('success');
    }
});
```

If you know any tips, please give me advice.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721970/jquery-ajax-not-working-in-ie8-but-it-works-on-firefox-chrome?rq=1

Comment: Thanks Parasanna, I will take a look at the link.

Comment: The link contents did not work. If anyone knows the solution, please give me any advice.

Comment: What is the response code you get?